# How can you check if SKAction is already playing a file?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

I currently have two scenes in my game

When entering scene one music plays. When the game is over and the user enters scene two, the music stops. When opting to retry the game, the music plays again.

I attempted to code the music to play continuously

```
[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"YourFileName.extension" waitForCompletion:NO]];
```

This works fantastically in the sense that when the game is over, the music is still playing rather than being cut off. However, when opting to retry and entering scene one again, the music continues but is also triggered again, resulting in a duplication. This can keep happening.

Is there a way to detect if the audio is already playing so that it won't continue to get triggered every time I enter scene one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bool initialized to NO:

```
bool isMusicPlaying;
```

When you start the music, set the bool to YES and make sure music does not get started if already playing :

```
if(isMusicPlaying == NO)
{
    [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"YourFileName.extension" waitForCompletion:NO]];
    isMusicPlaying = YES;
}
```

Comment: How do you carry the BOOL value across scenes? At the moment when I enter the end scene, the music is still playing (great). Clicking retry and returning to the game scene triggers the music again, resulting in the overlap (original issue) I'm assuming that upon returning to the game scene, the BOOL value is going to reset to NO? Am I correct in thinking that?

Comment: Store the bool in a class that you can reference from any scene.  I would recommend just using the class that you store your user data in.

Comment: Thanks again Meisenman - I stored the BOOL in the main view controller. However, what i'm finding is (when setting break points on the bool) is that the method works to ensure it's set to yes, but when checking the same value in the end of game class, it's just not receiving the updated value.